# Set Output directory in C++ one folder up

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

I am using a header library in my code to set my output directory. I would be running almost 12000 executables in parallel and I want a common output folder which is one level up. Here is how I use it

```
 global::directories().setOutputDir("./outputfolder/");
```

where `outputfolder` is a folder in the current directory with the executable. I would like this string to be one folder up directory (somethong like ../outputfolder)

Unfortunately `setOutputDir` takes inputs as string (http://www.palabos.org/documentation/develguide/globalDefs_8h_source.html)

I looked around and found that boost library would be the most appropriate way to achieve what I want. Just wanted to know if there can be a workaround using the standard C++ before I delve into the library

Thanks..

Comment: I don't get the "unfortunately" part. Why doesn't the string "../outputfolder" work?

Comment: think I got it......there seem to be a typo on my full path...thanks